# Progress bar increase precentage on load

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar, antd

I'm working on a simple progress bar that increases the percentage on load using reactjs and ant design, my problem is I cant achieve that effect.

Hope you understand me.

Thanks.

[SMAPLE CODE](https://codesandbox.io/s/5yj1mz103l)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      percent: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    let percent = this.state.percent;
    for (; percent < 40; percent++) {
      this.setState({
        percent: percent
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Progress percent={this.state.percent} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the percent loop in `componentDidUpdate`. So it won't trigger until the component is updated (which it isn't anywhere else in your code). If you change it to `componentDidMount` it'll do the loop right away. Review React lifecycle methods and when they trigger.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be using `setState()` inside `componentDidUpdate` since you can potentially cause infinite loops.

Comment: ok sir, thank you for that advice, It work. Ill just work on the animation to make it smooth on load

Comment: No worries. Please mark the answer as correct so people know the question is solved :)

Comment: sorry, im still waiting for the time.